# Spyder versions in Anaconda environments

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am still new to Anaconda and just created a new environment as follows:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

After this if I run these two command after each other:

```
conda activate py27
spyder
```

It launches spyder version 3. However when I run the `spyder` command from the `(base)` environment it starts spyder version 4.

Why is this and should I upgrade in the py27 environment?